# Representative of cycle type $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Exhibit a representative of each cycle type of $A_5$ as a commutator in $S_5$.

So, in General how can I solve this problem do I have to test all elements of $S_5$ to get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

Some elements:

- $A_5$ cycle types are: product of two permutations, 3-cycles and 5-cycles.
- By a conjugaison argument, we can focus on following elements of $A_5$: $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4), (1 \ 2 \ 3), (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5)$.
- If $(a_1 \ a_2 \ \dots a_k)$ is a cycle and $\sigma$ a permutation, the commutator $\sigma (a_1 \ a_2 \ \dots a_k) \sigma^{-1} (a_1 \ a_2 \ \dots a_k)^{-1}$ is equal to $(\sigma(a_1) \ \sigma(a_2) \ \dots \sigma(a_k)) (a_1 \ a_2 \ \dots a_k)^{-1}$

Now we deal for example with $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$. Take for $\sigma$ the permutation with $\sigma(3)=1, \sigma(4)=2, \sigma(1)=3, \sigma(2)=4, \sigma(5)=5$. Then $\sigma (3 \ 4) \sigma^{-1} (3 \ 4)^{-1}=(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$.

You can follow on on this basis for the other cases.